# How to set callback function as prop for react-paginate and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

react-paginate has a prop: `onPageChange` and the type is:

`onPageChange?(selectedItem: { selected: number }): void;`

but after using it like this:

```
const onPageChange = (selected): void => {
    console.log(selected);
}

<Pagination
  pageCount={pageCount}
  onPageChange={onPageChange}
/>
```

I've this error:

```
Parameter 'selected' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7006

    131 |   }
    132 | 
  > 133 |   const onPageChange = (selected): void => {
        |                         ^
    134 |     console.log(selected);
    135 |   }
    136 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add type for `selected`:

```
const onPageChange = ({selected}: { selected: number }): void => {
    console.log(selected);
}
```

Comment: I've this error for now: `Type '(selected: number) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2322)`

Comment: the complete error text:
```
Type '(selected: number) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.  TS2322

    155 |               <Pagination
    156 |                 pageCount={paginationProperties.pages}
  > 157 |                 onPageChange={onPageChange}
        |                 ^
    158 |               />
    159 |             </>
    160 | 
```

Comment: it's really strange... again has error: `Type '({ selected }: { selected: number; }) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.  TS2322`

Comment: You are ussing `onPageChange` on the other position

Comment: is it because the same function names?

Comment: No. Please check your file again. You are ussing `onPageChange` on the other position

Answer (score 0):

add any as type for ***selected***

```
const onPageChange = (selected:any): void => {
  console.log(selected); 
}
```